# Query optimization (Datagrip)

Tags: sql, optimization, google-analytics, amazon-athena, datagrip

What does make my query weight so much and how to optimize it?
I need to calculate the unique purchases happening in the same time as an event. So the user should click on the specific CTA with an event label = "seller_estimation" and CD36 = "listpage" and in the same session to make a purchase with product = kostenloseimmobilienbewertung, CD65 like "%/successsellpage" and CD42 like "verkaufen" or "sell"

```
WITH Search_Result_Page AS (SELECT
DISTINCT CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitid AS VARCHAR)) AS sessionId
FROM HeroKpiProd.aviv_herokpi_prd_traffic_raw.ga_iwt,
UNNEST(hits) AS t(hit),
UNNEST(hit.customDimensions) AS t(cd)
WHERE
hit.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'seller_estimation'
AND year >= 2022
AND cd.index = 36
AND cd.value = 'listpage')

SELECT
    ds_month,
    'Search_Result_Page' as placement,
    viewid,
    SUM(unique_purchases) as leads
FROM
(SELECT
    CAST(CAST(year AS varchar) || '-' || CAST(month AS varchar) || '-' || CAST(01 AS varchar) AS DATE) AS ds_month,
    viewid,
    CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitid AS VARCHAR)) AS sessionId,
    COUNT(DISTINCT hit.transaction.transactionid) AS unique_purchases
FROM XXXXX,
       unnest(customdimensions) as t(customdimensions),
       UNNEST(hits) AS t(hit),
       UNNEST(hit.product) AS t(product),
       UNNEST(product.customDimensions) as t(productcustomdimensions),
       UNNEST(hit.customdimensions) AS t(cd)
WHERE cd.index = 65
AND cd.value LIKE '%/successsellpage'
AND productcustomdimensions.index = 42
AND productcustomdimensions.value IN ('verkaufen', 'sell')
AND  year >= 2022
AND viewid IN  ('96019039', '96019039')
AND product.v2ProductName = 'kostenlose_immobilienbewertung'
AND CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitid AS VARCHAR))  IN (SELECT * FROM Search_Result_Page)
GROUP BY 1, 2,3)
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

> Query is not loading since it is weighting too much

Comment: How many rows does this return? A [mre] would be nice too (though probably impossible)? Have you tried running it in Athena UI?

Comment: Is that the actual error message? Did you copy & paste it, or re-type it, because it seems a strange choice of words. Also, which system gave you that message -- did it come from the database (Athena?), or did it come from DataGrip itself?

Comment: The query is working itself in Athena, but I am getting a timeout error when I copy it in the Tableau custom query field.